# Taking only first string from paste value in input value

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, copy-paste

I want to get only the first value from copy-paste value.

For example:
my copy text is: **Lorem Lipsum Test**

So when I copied this above text and paste it into the HTML input filed there need to come only **"Lorem"** I don't need other text

Is there any way to achieve these things?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You just need to copy first value only to do that no need to complicate things. Also if you need this functionality than provide some code of what you have tried till now.

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying me. I have one input field there take value when i scan qr code. so in qr code have many text, but i want only first string from the qr code. so this is reason if i split it i can get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it only returns always the first word from string input and you have to clear for copy new value then it's show first word of the new copied string.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   
  $("#getfirstword").on("keyup", function(e) {
  debugger
    // do stuff!
     var str =  $(this).val();
//Now i separate them by "|"
var str1 = str.split('|');

//Now i want to get the first word of every split-ed sting parts:
 var firstWord ="";
for (var i=0;i<str1.length;i++)
{
    //What to do here to get the first word :)
  firstWord = str1[i].split(' ')[0];
    
}
$("#input1").val(firstWord);
})
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

 <input id="getfirstword" /> 
<input id="input1" disabled/> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you its working perfectly, thank you so much for help me. I mark your answer it correct. but i have one small question. How can i set it as input value? Sorry for bothering you brother.

Comment: Set it as input value means you want to set this value to other input or in same input?

Comment: updated code as you ask how to set it as input value here is on disabled input in which I set the first word from the input.

Comment: great you're really awesome. If i want to reset this value after 5 second. is there anyway to reset this value after 5 second. sorry for bothering you again.

Comment: you have to use the set timeout jquery function.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an input event to see what you are trying to add to your element. This code will split your pasted text and only add the first word.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const log = document.getElementById('values');

input.addEventListener('input', updateValue);
var previousValue = "";

function updateValue(e) {
  log.textContent = e.data;
  if (e.data && e.inputType == "insertFromPaste") {
    if (e.data.length > 1) {
      let val = e.data.split(" ")[0];
      let str = previousValue + val;
      e.target.value = str;
    }
  }
  previousValue = e.target.value;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Enter some text" name="name"/>
<p id="values"></p>
```